# Finding intersection, complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

I cannot get the intersection out right. How do you find the locus of complex numbers $z$ satisfying this equation?
$$|z-1|=|z|$$
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that you have commented on an answer "The points of intersection is supposed to be 1/2 +- 3/2i", **there is more to this question than you have put here**.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

note that $|z-1|$ is the distance of $z$ from $1$ and $|z|$ is the distance of $z$ from $0$.  So, when  these two distances are the same?

Comment: The points of intersection is supposed to be 1/2 +- 3/2i, I just cant get that out, been trying for a while but hasn't achieved that yet....

Comment: Write $z=a+bi$ and realize that $|a+bi-1|^2$ is $(a-1)^2+b^2$.

Comment: All the numbers $z=x+iy$ with $x=1/2$ are such that $|z-1|=|z|$. It  is not clear what is the ''intersection'' that you want.

Comment: @imranfat "realize" :  well chosen verb in this context...

Comment: @Stratbomber: maybe that your problem is this one ?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1977251/finding-the-intersecting-points-on-two-circles-in-the-complex-plane

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $z = x+iy$, and solve for $x$ and $y$...You will then get your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The equation is equivalent to

$$(z-1)(z^*-1)=zz^*,$$

hence

$$1-z-z^*=1-2\Re z=0.$$

Comment: ahh, okay, I see, what is the $2Rz$ then ?