# Finding the intersecting points on two circles in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I am trying to find the intersecting points on the circles:
$$|z-1|=1$$ and $$|z|=1$$  where $z$ is a complex number.
I know that the answer should be $z=1/2$ $\pm$ $i\sqrt3$/2 but i'm not sure how to get there?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|z-1|=1 \implies |z-1|^2=1$ remember that $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$, hence $(z-1)(\overline{z-1})=(z-1)(\overline{z}-1)=1$ or $$z\overline{z}-\overline{z}-z+1=1.$$ For the second equation you will get $$z\overline{z}=1.$$

You will directy get: $z+\overline{z}=1 \implies 2\Re\{z\}=1$. Then plug this into $z\overline{z}=1$ to determine $\Im \{z\}$.

Comment: managed to solve it now, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You're looking for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that
\begin{equation}
(a-1)^2+b^2=1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
a^2+b^2=1.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

from $|z-1|=|z|$ you see that $z$ is equidistant from $1$ and $0$, so $z=x+iy$ with $x=1/2$. and we want: 
$$
|z|^2=x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}+y^2=1
$$